# Use jquery to set a hidden input value using attr of an image

Tags: jquery

Let's say for example I have some images

```
<img class="selectImage" src="..." value="John" />
<img class="selectImage" src="..." value="Sally" />
<img class="selectImage" src="..." value="Joe" />
```

When  an image is clicked I want the value of

```
 <input type="hidden" name="First Name" />
```

to become the value of "value="

Comment: Thanks I've corrected the appropriate markup to reflect this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var hinput = $('input[name="First Name"]');
    $('.selectImage').click(function(){
        hinput.val($(this).attr('value'))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UrQSu/)

Comment: I think `.attr()` has been deprecated. One should use `.prop()` instead.

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj not for this use case... here `value` is an attribute in the html element

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('img.selectImage').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myVal = $(this).attr("value");
        $('input:hidden[name="First Name"]').val(myVal);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) for associating data with an element, rather then the `value` attribute which, as others have said, is not valid markup.

Change your html to be formatted like so:

```
<img class="selectImage" src="..." data-firstname="John" />
```

You can then access the [`data-*` attribute with JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/) as follows:

```
var x = $("selector").data("firstname");//get
$("selector").data("firstname", x);//set
```

The complete code for your requirements is as follows:

```
$('.selectImage').click(function(){
    var firstName = $(this).data("firstname");
    $('input[name="First Name"]').val(firstName);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BhrPX/)